# compress two consecutive dimension in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch

I'm looking for such a function `Tensor.compress(*dims)` where `dims=(int ...)` is a **consecutive sequence of integer**:

```py
a = torch.rand(2,2,3)
b = a.compress(0,1)

b.size()
>>> (4,3)
```

I know `view` would work, however, in case I don't know the shape of `a` in advance, I have to do an extra operation to acquire its size and then do `view`, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to explicitly "do the math", [`torch.view`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.view.html#torch.Tensor.view) can do some of it for you if you use `-1` as the shape of one of the dimensions:

```py
b = a.view(-1, *a.shape[2:])
b.shape
>>> torch.Size([4, 3])
```